# Get url parameter and insert into database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Trying to insert into database by typing the value in the url, but having difficulties to insert into the database:

Here is the URL:

```
http://student.cs.hioa.no/~s180343/updatedb.php?verdi=22
```

Here is the code:

```
<?php

$dbhost = "MYSQL-SERVER";
$dbuser = "USERNAME";
$dbpass = "";
$verdi = $_GET['verdi'];

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO test ('id') VALUES (`$verdi`)";

mysql_select_db('s180350');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: what's the error you're getting?  What type of column is ID?  It looks like you're trying to send a string, but the value is an integer.

Answer (score 4):

Use quotes around your string values. Use ticks around your column names. You have it backwards:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test ('id') VALUES (`$verdi`)";
```

shjould be

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (`id`) VALUES ('$verdi')";
```

FYI, you are wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: not to mention the deprecation of the mysql_* functions :D

Answer (score 1):

You are doing reverse i.e. adding `''` for column name and `` for the value

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test ('id') VALUES (`$verdi`)";
```

should be

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (`id`) VALUES ('$verdi')";
```

Start using prepare statement or at least below after conn is defined.

```
$verdi = mysql_real_escape_string($verdi);
```

Answer (score 0):

please dont forget to secure all user input into your sql querys. see [SQL injection wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

The problem with your code is wrong use on quotes. See edited code:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("MYSQL-SERVER", "USERNAME", $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('s180350');

$retval = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO test ('id') VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['verdi'])"')", $conn );

if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "Entered data successfully\n";
```

PS: Dont use up resources by setting variables you dont need.